# Boolean method keeps returning true

Tags: java, boolean

Please help me understand why the boolean method I wrote is not returning appropriately. I ask the user to enter a series of ints to be stored in an array which is checked for duplicates.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PokerHands 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(containsPair(welcome()));
    } // end main

    private static int[] welcome()
    {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] poker_array = new int[5];

        System.out.println("Enter five numeric cards, no face cards. Use 2-9: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Card %d: ", i + 1);
            int nums = read.nextInt();
            while (nums < 2 || nums > 9) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input. Choose from 2-9 only: ");
            nums = read.nextInt();
            } // end while
        poker_array[i] = nums;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < poker_array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(poker_array[i] + ", ");
        }

        return poker_array;
    } // end welcome()

    private static boolean containsPair(int hand[])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < hand.length; j++) {
                if (hand[i] == hand[j]) {
                    return true;
                } // end if
            } // end inner for
        } // end outer for

        return false;
    } // end containsPair()
} //end class
```

Output:
$ java PokerHands

Enter five numeric cards, no face cards. Use 2-9:

Card 1: 2

Card 2: 3

Card 3: 4

Card 4: 5

Card 5: 6

2, 3, 4, 5, 6, true

$ java PokerHands
Enter five numeric cards, no face cards. Use 2-9:

Card 1: 2

Card 2: 2

Card 3: 3

Card 4: 4

Card 5: 5

2, 2, 3, 4, 5, true

$ java PokerHands

Enter five numeric cards, no face cards. Use 2-9:

Card 1: 2

Card 2: 2

Card 3: 2

Card 4: 2

Card 5: 2

2, 2, 2, 2, 2, true

Comment: `i` and `j` will start at `0` so you will be comparing the same element, which will be equal to itself and the method will return true

Answer (score 1):

It's because for 1st pass, `i=0` and `j=0`. So it will always return true. You should initialize `j=i+1`

Comment: initialize j = i+1 but is array[i] = array[j] the same as array[j] = array[i] ?

Comment: What do you mean?  Please check your program by changing j=i+1.

Comment: I did. I just want to understand what j=i+1 represents. Is it the int next to the int on i[0]?

Comment: If i=0, j will be 1. So you would start comparing array[0] with array[1] and so on..

Comment: As @Amit said.  When i = 0 then hand[i] is the first card. j = i+1 so j is 1. hand[j] is the second card.  As j increases you are comparing first card with second, then first card with third, then first card with fourth until you get to the end of the hand.

Comment: Then when i is 1 and j is 2 you will compare the second card with the third, then the second card with the fourth, then the second card with the fifth and so on.  Each cycle though the outer loop will get shorter as there are fewer cards after the one being looked at.   You will never compare a card with itself, and you will save a lot of comparison opertions.....

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the if in your boolean to the following:

```
if (hand[i] == hand[j] && i != j)
```

Comment: You should also explain why it will change the result.

Answer (score 0):

Change method with HashSet usage. 
Code will be like this

```
private static boolean containsPair(int hand[])
{
    //adding to list all elements
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i : hand) {
        intList.add(i);
    }
    //put all elements to set
    HashSet<Integer> zipcodeSet = new HashSet<>(intList);
    //if size not match , has a dublicate
    return zipcodeSet.size() != hand.length;

} // end containsPair()
```